# Did Anakin Skywalker ever use a Blaster?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, anakin-skywalker

**Did Anakin ever use a blaster rifle or a pistol in the Star Wars Universe?** If so, then what timeline in the Prequel Trilogy? Answers can be taken from the movies, novels, TV series (Clone Wars), etc..

Comment: His [action figure](https://www.amazon.com/Star-Wars-Skywalker-Removable-Container/dp/B000063CUW) has one...

Comment: do you mean a handheld blaster? Otherwise, one could be very pedantic and say that the Naboo Starfighter could count :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the lost episode of [Star Wars: The Clone Wars - In Search of the Crystal](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/In_Search_of_the_Crystal) (incomplete, but considered [fully canon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Clone_Wars_Legacy)) Anakin demonstrates his capacity and competence with a blaster.

[image]

You can view the full sequence here

---

He (very briefly) *threatens* [Shahan Alama](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shahan_Alama/Legends) with his own blaster before Aurra Sing shoots it out of his hand in [Star Wars: The Clone Wars - Hostage Crisis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hostage_Crisis).

[image]